# How to create Action space in GYM with range from 0 to 10 with 0.5 difference between the consecutive actions?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, openal, markov-decision-process

I intend to create Action space in GYM with range from 0 to 10

```
I want action space like [0 0.5 1 ..... 10]
```

Comment: The simplest way to do it is to use a continuous action and discretize on the environment-side : use Box(low=0, high=10, shape=(1,)), and then round the value of the action to the closest multiple of 0.5. 

You could also use a discrete action space of size len([0 0.5 ... 10]) but using a discrete action space might be detrimental to learning as the algorithm see each value as being completely different than the others (0 is not more similar to 0.5 than 10 in the way the algorithm will work)

Comment: OK thanks i will try this

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use Enum. See below

```
from enum import Enum
class Actions(Enum):
     action1 = 0
     action2 = 1
     action3 = 2

# when you call
action == Actions.action2.value
```